# Input colando nos Radios

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou construindo um `form`, aonde tenho dois `radios inline` e um `input` em baixo. Só que não sei porque o `input` está colando nos `radios`, deixando o `form` todo desalinhado. Esse é o código:

```
<section class="col col-3">                                     
    <div class="form-inline">
        <!--ng-show='pessoa.id_tipo_pessoa == 1'-->
        <div class="form-group" ng-show="labelPF">
            <input type="radio" ng-model='pessoa.id_tipo_pessoa' value="1" onClick="$('#cadastroPF-form').clearValidation();" ng-click="pessoa.cnpj=''" id="pf">
            <i></i>CPF
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-show="labelPJ">
            <input type="radio" ng-model='pessoa.id_tipo_pessoa' value="2" onClick="$('#cadastroPF-form').clearValidation();" ng-click="pessoa.cpf=''" id="pj">
            <i></i>CNPJ     
        </div>
    </div>
    <label ng-show='pessoa.id_tipo_pessoa == 1' class="input">
        <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
        <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" data-mask="999.999.999-99" placeholder="Número CPF" ng-model="pessoa.cpf" ng-blur="getCpf('cpf')">
    </label>
    <label ng-show='pessoa.id_tipo_pessoa == 2' class="input">
        <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
        <input type="text" name="cnpj" id="cnpj" data-mask="99.999.999/9999-99" placeholder="Número CNPJ" ng-model="pessoa.cnpj" ng-blur="getCnpj('cnpj')">
    </label>
</section>
```

Comment: Joguei teu código no codepen e não entendi a pergunta, o problema é o radio estar colado no input? Porque aí é só colocar um margin.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, vi que está usando o bootstrap. Se ele for a versão 3 você pode fazer assim ho.

1- Dessa forma os radios ficam encima do input

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Inline radios</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" checked="checked"> Foobar
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radio"> Another
        </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Full part name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
```

2- Dessa forma o radio fica posicionado na frente do input

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" checked="checked"> Foobar
     </label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
```